# Find text between string

Tags: regex, perl

How to extract text using perl from string like this:

---

```
Get text 1 ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Get text 2 ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Get text 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result should be like this:

```
%texts =  ( 'text1' => 'Get text 1 ...', 'text2' => 'Get text 2 ...',
'text3' => 'Get text 3 ...' )
```

Something like PHP `preg_match_all`.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your preg_macth_all looks like `preg_match_all('/(foo)/', $text, $matches)`, the perl equivalent is something like `@matches = $text=~/(foo)/g`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but the following code extracts the lines from the string you gave and puts them in a hash:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'Get text 1 ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Get text 2 ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Get text 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';


my %hash = (
    'text1' => $str =~ /.*text 1.*/g,
    'text2' => $str =~ /.*text 2.*/g,
    'text3' => $str =~ /.*text 3.*/g);


print Dumper(\%hash);
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'text2' => 'Get text 2 ...',
          'text1' => 'Get text 1 ...',
          'text3' => 'Get text 3'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $i = 1;
my %text = ();
open my $fh, "<", \$the_string;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/--------------/) {  # text separator
        $i++;
    } else {
        $text{"text$i"} .= $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl >= 5.10, this should be:

```
while( $string =~ /^\w+\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)[^\n\r]*/pgms ) {
   $texts{$1.$2} = ${^MATCH}
}
```

Regards

rbo